# How to make an array inside a function be usable throughout the whole page

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array that is made inside of a function like this:

```
function easy() {
    var colors = ["white", "red", "orange", "yellow", "green", "blue", "purple", "gray", "white", "red", "orange", "yellow", "green", "blue", "purple", "gray"];
}
```

I call this function through an onclick on a radio button, but when I do this later:

```
colors.sort(function() {return 0.5 - Math.random()});
```

it doesn't work, I think it might be because colors is just a local array. Is there any way to make it work throuhttp://stackoverflow.com/posts/21558099/editghout the whole page?

Comment: declare it outside the function.

Comment: What is the purpose of that function?

Comment: to say what "colors" is, if the user clicks on a different radio button, "colors" would be different.

Comment: Are you trying to [**shuffle your array**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6274339/how-can-i-shuffle-an-array-in-javascript) of colors each time?

Comment: each time what happens?

Comment: each time you call your `easy` function?

Comment: It's unclear what your interface is here (how you want to use this).

Comment: No, I want it to be called only once, after the easy function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you declare your array outside of the function its scope is global :

```
var colors;
function easy() {
    colors = ["white", "red", "orange", "yellow", "green", "blue", "purple", "gray", "white", "red", "orange", "yellow", "green", "blue", "purple", "gray"];
}
easy(); // Here colors is defined;
```

Comment: I need to call easy through an onclick event though.

Comment: Does it make a difference that I'm calling the function through an onclick event?

Comment: No if the var is declared in the global scope.

Answer (score 0):

```
var colors;
function easy() {
   colors = ["white", "red", "orange", "yellow", "green", "blue", "purple", "gray", "white", "red", "orange", "yellow", "green", "blue", "purple", "gray"];
};
easy();
colors.sort(function() {return 0.5 - Math.random()});
```

Comment: Sorry, it was a typo. Just fixed it

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking to encapsulate it?

```
var easy = {
   colors: ["white", "red", "orange", "yellow", "green", "blue", "purple", "gray", "white", "red", "orange", "yellow", "green", "blue", "purple", "gray"],
   hello: function() { alert("Hello") }
}

alert( easy.colors.sort(function() {return 0.5 - Math.random()}) );
easy.hello();
```

Answer (score -1):

Probably you will need to use that variable in several programs. Put it in an external file, php an add it via include. Consider it like global variables.

Comment: This is extremely needlessly complicated for something that's simply accomplished by moving the variable to global scope.

Comment: In my scneario: "Probably you will need to use that variable in several programs". I have 20+ sites running in different host servers. For me, add/replace a new global variable means change only one program and replace only one program to all. For me, is extremely useful.